# Externally loaded Contact Form works slowly

Tags: performance, forms, text, input, contacts

I have made an external swf file for contact form.

I'm loading the contact form to primary swf using script:

*ContactMC.loadMovie("Contact.swf");*

The actual Contact.swf works great, but when I load it into the primary swf, the input text fields work very slowly.

The problem must be in primary swf, 'cause every input text that I make inside it won't work smoothly.

Any idea to correct the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The fps of the primary swf was set too slow (0.5).